# The silence of the Rabbis -- Should they have defended Bar Kamtza?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rabbis, derech-eretz-manners, churban-destruction, maseches-gitin

In [Gittin 55b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=55b&format=pdf)-56a, we read that a fellow named Bar Kamtza was humiliated by a host of a party in public view of all, including the rabbis.  Bar Kamtza received an invitation to the party by mistake, but did not know of the mistake, and assumed that the host was ending an old feud.  Bar Kamtza suggested numerous compromises to avoid humiliation, but his host accepted none, and threw him out on his ear.

Bar Kamtza then said to himself:  “Since the Rabbis were sitting there and did not stop him, this shows that they agreed with him. I will go and inform against them to the government.”  He then plotted to put the rabbis into a situation where they would have to choose between violating halacha and upsetting the Romans.  They chose the latter course, and this, the Gemara says, led to the siege of Jerusalem and its eventual destruction by the Romans.

Question:  How do the commentators view the apparent silence of the rabbis during Bar Kamtza's humiliation?  Did they actually witness the event?  If they did, did they have a duty to intervene and stop the host?  Do any commentators take the rabbis to task for their silence?  Sorry to ask multiple questions, but I think they are all related and relevant to us today.

Comment: "Do any commentators take the rabbis to task for their silence?" This is, indeed, how I've understood the story. The rabbis were taken to task by God and Jerusalem was sacked. But I've no source (at the moment) so am not posting this as an answer. +1, anyway.

Comment: @msh210 I appreciate the addition of tags I hadn't thought of, and I know one I suggested has not been introduced yet, but I'd like to see it.  I'll take it to Meta.

Comment: It would be difficult to take them to task had they not witnessed it. I think of this as a shtika k'hoda'ah situation plus a bit of hamalbin et pnei chaveiro plus lo ta'amod al dam er'echa.

Comment: @msh210 Were the rabbis taken to task for not defending Bar Kamtza or not killing him?  I seem to recall more discussion of the latter.  A rav yesterday told me that the Gemara appears to be giving us only one side of the story - Bar Kamtza's - but it would appear to me that if the Gemara knew that the rabbis were not a witness, it would have given there side, too, and not just Bar Kamtza's.

Comment: Perhaps "the rabbis" should not be viewed as a monolith. The rabbis at the party were silent, but the greatest rabbis of the generation (probably including those whose names are actually recorded in the Talmud) might not even have attended. Consider the *b'raisa* (*Sanhedrin* 23a): "כך היו נקיי הדעת שבירושלים עושין ... ולא היו נכנסין בסעודה אלא אם כן יודעין מי מיסב עמהן." Would the greatest sages have therefore attended the party of a wicked person? (Also consider P'sachim 49a, which lambasts Torah scholars who party to excess).

Comment: Talking out of my hat I would say: looking at the outcome of the story that he went to the government etc. it tells us about his character in general and that's why the host hated him and my guess is he had some 'running-in' with the sages in the past etc. to the degree that they did not have the obligation to stop the host. (As we see it says the destruction was because of Sinas Chinnom, it doesn't say, because of lack of admonishing!.)   In other words, the host was not allowed to hate him, but the sages had no obligation to stop the host's actions. -Just my thoughts.

Comment: @Fred I would have up-voted your comment three or four times if I could.  Yashir koach!

Comment: See the version of the story in Midrash Eicha, brought in this answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9363/603

Comment: @msh210 given the introduction by Rabbi Yohanan about being cautious and considering potential ramifications of actions, my understanding was that everyone in the story is taken to task, from Bar Kamzta to Titus

Answer (score 7):

*Maharsha* writes on that story:

> **הואיל והוו יתבי רבנן ולא מיחו בו:** איכא למימר מה שלא מיחו מפני שלא היה בידם למחות אפשר שעשו כן כי החנופה היא שגברה באותו הדור כמ"ש בסוטה
>   גבי אגריפס המלך
>
> One could say that the reason that the rabbis didn't object was
>   because they were not able to object. It's also possible that they did
>   this out of flattery, which was all too common in those times, like we
>   find by King Aggripas.

(*translation mine*)

Comment: What does he mean that "they were not able to object"?  Also, I'm not sure what he is saying when he says "they did this out of flattery."  How was not objecting to a man's poor treatment "flattery"?

Comment: On your first point, @BruceJames, I'm not sure. That's what he says...I think it could mean that things happened so fast that they weren't able to say anything, or that there was some other factor that prevented them from getting involved, that wasn't their fault. On your second point, I think that the "flattery" mentioned is toward Kamtza, not Bar Kamtza; though I'm not certain, because I don't know what the story with King Aggripas is about.

Comment: When I translated this, I wasn't sure if the *Maharsha* intended two answers, or one.....I was hoping someone here would critique my translation. Do you think it would make more sense if it was one big explanation, @BruceJames?

Answer (score 1):

1) The Chasam Sofer (Chidushei Chasam Sofer Gittin 55b) cites an explanation for the Rabbis' conduct (this is an abbreviated version of what he says): They thought the host must have witnessed Bar Kamtza engage in the type of immoral behavior that would make it halachically legitimate to act hatefully towards him. However (he continues), even according to their assumption, they still should have gone beyond the letter of the law and objected.

2) Rabbi Avigdor Miller (Torah Nation chapter 7 section 685-687) suggests that the Sages were correct to not defend Bar Kamtza - for historical documentation shows that Bar Kamtza was already aligned with the Roman enemies of the Jews, and as the Gemara notes in Sanhedrin 23a, the Sages of Jerusalem had standards for who was fit to be at a seudah together with them.

Comment: This shows they were consistently applying their rules, but does that make them correct? Perhaps they should have made an exception to avoid the Temple burning and thousands of Jews being murdered, raped, and exiled?

Comment: @DoubleAA -  I believe the Gemara in Gittin is clear that the destruction was still easily avoidable even after he was thrown out, so no they were quite correct not to make an exception.

Comment: More fundamentally, even though they knew Bar Kamtza wasn't  exactly a great guy, they didn't realize just how diabolical he was.

Comment: @Jay So proper conduct is completely dependent on the type of person you may possibly be screwing over?

Comment: @Aaron -  If you are questioning the practice of the Sages in general not to be together with certain people at a seudah - the Gemara in Sanhedrin seems to cite the practice approvingly, and I trust the Sages understanding of what is halachically the correct practice/proper conduct. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @Jay Saying you trust the sages is not an answer. "Q: Why would allowing Bar Kamtza to stay at the meal be so bad as to be worth the Temple burning and thousands of Jews being murdered, raped, and exiled? A: I trust the sages." See?

Comment: @DoubleAA -  It seems you didn't read my entire comment. I made it clear I was responding to questioning the practice in general.

Comment: @Jay I did read it. And a problem with one instance indicates a problem with the practice in general. Unless you know how to pick out a priori the cases where the specific problem might arise? Any general rule which occasional ends up with the Temple burning and thousands of Jews being murdered, raped, and exiled is questionable, to say the least.

Comment: Bar Kamtza's behavior was  bizarre and  abnormal  - it is not something that would be anticipated when formulating a general policy. And, as I pointed out above, the Gemara seems to cite the practice approvingly.

Comment: Again, the assertion that the Sages should have objected in order to prevent the destruction is erroneous for 2 reasons: 1) They did not anticipate Bar Kamtzah's extreme, bizarre reaction , and 2) Even after his reaction, the destruction was still avoidable, as it indicates in the Gemara in Gittin.

Comment: @Jay I think you are misusing the term erroneous. It's not erroneous. When forming any general policy one must consider exceptional cases and how to handle them. We agree his reaction was atypical. But sometimes you account for atypical things to avoid catastrophe. It's like buying insurance or hedging your bet. I don't think you really get the issue here.

Comment: @DoubleAA -  No, not every bizarre possibility must be considered. There is a line between  exceptional cases that are to be anticipated, and exceedingly unlikely cases which need not be anticipated when formulating  a policy.

Comment: @Jay I didn't deny that.

Comment: @Jay Let me ask you this, if they would have stood up for, or intervened in humiliation of Bar Kamtza, would they have been doing something wrong?

Comment: @Aaron - Rabbi Miller's approach seems to be that whatever reason they had for their policy in general, also motivated them to be silent, so yes they would be doing something wrong.  I  admittedly find this part of the approach to be something of a chiddush, because the Gemara in Sanhedrin only says they would avoid coming in the first place.

Comment: @Jay It's funny to note that anything new is not from the Torah, unless of course that new thing puts the sages in a better light. This is not an attempt to say anything bad about the sages, but for me personally, if the sages never erred, then they have no value to me, because they become unrelatable.

Comment: @Aaron - The Gemara in Gittin seems to say they did indeed err, just not at that point in the story, rather later on when Rabbi Zechariah ben Avkulas made his fateful decisions which were accepted - see 56a.

Comment: @Jay saying they specifically erred in one thing, does not mean they were guiltless of anything else. If i say that such and such is guilty of hitting his wife, that doesn't mean he was innocent of anger, or drunkenness, etc. etc.

Comment: @Aaron - I didn't mean it's a proof that they didn't err earlier. I just meant to point out that no one is saying they were incapable of making a mistake - the Gemara itself contradicts that notion.